# Universal property of tensor products of bounded operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, tensor-products

Consider the tensor product of bounded operators. Does this tensor product satisfy the universal property of the tensor product, i.e., for any bilinear map $F: B(\mathcal H_1)\times B(\mathcal H_2)\to B(\mathcal H)$, there is a unique map $\hat F: B(\mathcal H_1)\otimes B(\mathcal H_2)\to B(\mathcal H)$ such that $\hat F(a\otimes b)=F(a,b)$?

**Clarifications:**

- I am flexible about what "map" (and "bilinear map") means here, as long as it is some subset of the linear maps. E.g., bounded linear maps, completely positive maps, etc.
- $B(\mathcal H)$ is the Banach space of bounded operators on the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$.
- The tensor product $B(\mathcal H_1)\otimes B(\mathcal H_2)$ is defined as follows: For operators $a,b$, the operator $a\otimes b\in B(\mathcal H_1\otimes'\mathcal H_2)$ is the unique operator with $(a\otimes b)(\psi\otimes'\phi)=a\psi\otimes' b\phi$, where $\otimes'$ is the Hilbert space tensor product. Then $B(\mathcal H_1)\otimes B(\mathcal H_2)$ is defined as the von-Neumann algebra generated by the $a\otimes b$. We have $B(\mathcal H_1)\otimes B(\mathcal H_2) = B(\mathcal H_1\otimes'\mathcal H_2)$ according to *Takesaki, Theory of
  Operator Algebras I*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is false in general even for very "well-behaved" classes of maps. For instance, the multiplication map on $B(H)$, which is bounded bilinear as a map $B(H)\times B(H) \to B(H)$, does not extend continuously to $B(H\otimes H)\to B(H)$ if $H$ is infinite-dimensional.

In fact, the problem is worse thane one might think, because at the level of matrices the extension of the product map $M_n \times M_n \to M_n$ to $M_{n^2} \to M_n$ has a norm which tends to infinity as $n\to \infty$. (I think the growth rate is $O(n)$ but I don't remember the details.)

The relevant universal property is that if $T_i \in B(H_i,K_i)$ for $i=1,2$ then $T_1\otimes T_2$ is a well-defined operator $H_1\otimes H_2\to K_1\otimes K_2$.

If one wants to linearize bilinear maps which are completely bounded (and there are two different notions of complete boundedness for bilinear maps) then you need either the operator-space projective tensor product or the Haagerup tensor product, rather than the spatial von Neumann tensor product that you describe in your question.

Comment: Thanks. (Though not what I had hoped.) Do you by any chance know a reference for this impossibility?

Comment: Do you know whether this impossibility also holds in the special case where we linearize $F(a,b):=G(a)\cdot H(b)$ where $G,H$ have commuting ranges (and $G,H$ are guaranteed to be bounded unital *-homomorphisms)?

Comment: This is also false assuming both G and H have domain B(E) where E is an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space; but it is true if either G or H is defined on a finite-dimensional matrix algebra, and the linearized map has norm 1, so this might be good enough for your purposes. The failure in the infinite-dimensional setting is because the appropriate tensor product for linearizing these special kinds of F is the maximal tensor product of Cstar algebras, and $B(E_1)\otimes_{\max} B(E_2)$ is not $B(E_1\otimes E_2)$ if $E_1$ and $E_2$ are infinite-dimensional

Comment: I think I understand. Since $\otimes_{\max}$ and $\otimes_\mathrm{spatial}$ both can be written as $F(-)\cdot G(-)$ (using $F(x):=x\otimes1$, $G(x):=1\otimes x$), if both tensor products satisfy the universal property, they can be shown isomorphic. And $\otimes_{\max}$ and $\otimes_\mathrm{spatial}$ are not isomorphic (in the ininite-dimensional case). The only chance to get a tensor product different from $\otimes_{\max}$ to satisfy my universal property would be for a notion of maps where $-\otimes_\max1$, $1\otimes_\max-$ are not maps.

Comment: Yemon, I found a [proof](https://mathoverflow.net/a/390392/101775) that the product of normal unital *-homomorphisms can be linearized w.r.t. von Neumann tensor product. Since that stands in contrast to what you said in your comment, you might be interested to have a look (and maybe tell me that I am wrong, though I hope not).

Comment: EDIT: the product of normal unital *-homomorphisms **with commuting ranges** can be linearized

Comment: @DominiqueUnruh: I have not checked your answer in detail, but it may be important that you are requiring these star homomorpisms to be **normal** (which you did not state in your previous comment). The point is that normal star-homomorphisms from B(H) to something else will be uniquely determined by their restriction to K(H). Now it is is true that a pair of star-homomorphisms $\phi_i:K(H_i)\to B(V)$ (i=1,2) with commuting ranges do admit a linearization in your sense: $\phi_1\otimes \phi_2 : K(H_1\otimes H_2) \to B(V)$, because we do have $K(H_1)\otimes_{\rm max} K(H_2)=K(H_1\otimes H_2)$.

Comment: Yes, normality was not in my earlier requirements because I had no clue it would be a useful property. Fortunately, as far as I can tell, normality is not a problem in my setting (it is a "well-behaved" class of maps). And thanks for the more compact proof sketch. :)

Answer (score 2):

One can say *something* positive, though it may not be useful.  You say you are willing to "be flexible about what map means".  Well, you could *define* the maps you are interested in to be those which extend!  For example, perhaps we want to end up with $\hat F:B(H_1\otimes H_2) \rightarrow B(H)$ which are weak$^*$-continuous and completely bounded.  Then just set your class of bilinear maps to be those $F$ which are given by
$$ F(a,b) = \hat F(a\otimes b), $$
for such a $\hat F$.

This is obviously a bit tautological.  Perhaps you had in mind which $F$ you "really" cared about.  You might ask again; or perhaps Yemon's answer has already dealt with the cases you want.

In Banach/Operator Space theory, it is common to study tensor products which don't really come from "universal properties" of this type.  For example, the [Injective Tensor Product](https://www.math.uni-sb.de/ag/wittstock/OperatorSpace/node53.html).  The maps this linearises would be "bilinear integral" maps, but I don't know if such things have really been studied.  Your question is somehow about a weak$^*$-version of this.  (In Banach Space theory one is interested in studying the dual space of tensor products: that is, which bilinear maps linearise where the codomain is the scalars.  For the injective norm you get the "integral operators".)

If you are interested in linearising the *product* map (as Yemon's answer discusses) then the relevant tensor product is the [(weak$^*$) Haagerup tensor product](https://www.math.uni-sb.de/ag/wittstock/OperatorSpace/node58.html).

Finally, though off-topic for this question, related is a [nice paper of Wiersma](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01671) which considers ways to tensor two von Neumann algebras: not from the perspective of a universal property, but rather variations on the "spatial" definition.

Comment: I *think* Yemon's answer covered my use case. I do currently need to linearize $F(-)\cdot G(-)$ for commuting-range $F,G$. But maybe I have some wiggle-room there that could allow me to use your idea. I will have to think more about it.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\range{\operatorname{range}}
\newcommand\B{\mathcal B}
\newcommand\H{\mathcal H}
\newcommand\K{\mathcal K}
$
We can achieve the universal property for certain bilinear maps of the specific form $F(x,y) = H(x) K(y)$. More precisely:

**Theorem:** Let $\mathcal H,\mathcal K,\mathcal L$ be Hilbert spaces. Let $H:\mathcal B(\mathcal H)\to\mathcal B(\mathcal L)$ and $K:\mathcal B(\mathcal K)\to\mathcal B(\mathcal L)$ be normal unital $*$-homomorphisms. Assume that the ranges of $H$ and $K$ commute. Then there is a normal unital *-homomorphism $G:\mathcal B(\mathcal H\otimes\mathcal K)\to \mathcal B(\mathcal L)$ such that $G(h\otimes k)=H(h)K(k)$.

**Proof:** By [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/390180/101775), $H(h)=U_H(h\otimes 1_{\mathcal H_0})U_H^*$ for some Hilbert space $\mathcal H_0$ and some unitary $U_H$. Thus $H=\hat H \circ \iota_H$ where $\hat H(x):=U_HxU_H^*$ and $\iota_H(h)=h\otimes 1_{\mathcal H_0}$. $\hat H$ is a unital $*$-isomorphism and therefore normal.
$\iota_H$ is a unital $*$-homomorphism. $\iota_H$ is weak*-continuous and therefore normal.
Analogously, we get that $K=\hat K\circ\iota_K$ for some normal unital *-isomorphism $\hat K$ and the normal unital *-homomorphism $\iota_K(k):=k\otimes 1_{\mathcal K_0}$. Let $\iota_0(x):=1_{\mathcal H}\otimes x$ for $x\in\mathcal H_0$, also a normal unital *-homomorphism.

The ranges of $H,K$ commute by assumption. Thus $\hat H(\mathcal B(\mathcal H)\otimes \mathbf 1)$ and $\hat K(\mathcal B(\mathcal K)\otimes \mathbf 1)$ commute. Here $\mathbf 1$ denotes the von Neumann algebra in $\mathcal B(\mathcal H_0),\mathcal B(\mathcal K_0)$, respectively, that consists of the multiples of identity. And $\otimes$ is tensor product of von Neumann algebras. Since $\hat H$ is a normal *-isomorphism, $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)\otimes\mathbf 1$ and $S:=\hat H^{-1}\hat K(\mathcal B(\mathcal K)\otimes\mathbf 1)$ commute and $S$ is a von Neumann algebra. Hence $$S \subseteq (\mathcal B(\mathcal H)\otimes\mathbf 1)' \stackrel{(*)}= \mathcal B(\mathcal H)'\otimes \mathbf 1' = \mathbf 1\otimes \mathcal B(\mathcal H_0) = \range \iota_0.$$
Here $X'$ denotes the commutant of $X$ and $(*)$ follows from the commutation theorem for tensor products of von Neumann algebras.

Since $\iota_0$ is an isometry, $\iota_0^{-1}:\mathbf 1\otimes\mathcal B(\mathcal H_0)\to\mathcal B(\mathcal H_0)$ exists and is a normal unital $*$-isomorphism.
Thus
$$
f : \mathcal B(\mathcal K) 
\overset{\iota_K}\longrightarrow
\mathcal B(\mathcal K) \otimes \mathbf 1
\overset{\hat H^{-1}\hat K}\longrightarrow
S
\overset{\iota_0^{-1}}\longrightarrow
\mathcal B(\mathcal H_0)
$$
is a composition of unital normal *-homomorphisms and hence a unital normal *-homomorphism.

Since $1_{\B(\H)}$ and $f$ are normal $*$-homomorphisms and thus completely positive, by [Tak, Prop. 5.13], $1_{\B(\H)}\otimes f:\B(\H\otimes\K)\to\B(\H\otimes\H_0)$ exists and is normal and completely positive. And it satisfies $(1_{\B(\H)}\otimes f)(h\otimes k)=1(h)\otimes f(k)$.
Then $1_{\B(\H)}\otimes f$ is also unital and bounded.
On the algebraic tensor product $\B(\K)\otimes_{\mathit{alg}}\B(\H)$, $1_{\B(\H)}\otimes f$ is a
*-homomorphism, and thus it is a *-homomorpism everywhere by continuity.
Let $G := \hat H\circ (1_{\mathcal B(\mathcal H)}\otimes f)$.
Since $\hat H$ is also a normal unital $*$-homomorpishm, so is $G$.

We have
$$
G(h\otimes 1_{\mathcal K}) = \hat H(h\otimes 1) = H(h)
$$
and
$$
G(1_{\mathcal H}\otimes k) = 
\hat H(1_{\mathcal H}\otimes f(k)) =
\hat H(\iota_0\circ f(k)) =
\hat H(\hat H^{-1}\circ\hat K\circ \iota_K(k)) =
\hat K\circ \iota_K(k) = K(k).
$$
Since $G$ is a *-homomorphism, this implies $G (h\otimes k) = G(h\otimes 1)G(1\otimes k)=H(h)K(k)$ as desired.

[Tak] *Takesaki, M.*, Theory of operator algebras I., Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences 124. Operator Algebras and Non-Commutative Geometry 5. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-42248-X/hbk). xix, 415 p. (2002). [ZBL0990.46034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0990.46034).